# Counterexamples for three propositions about groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Give counterexamples for these three propositions:

> 1. $G$ is a group and $G\triangleright A,B$ are normal subgroups of $G$. Then $G/A\cong B \Rightarrow G/B\cong A  $.
> 2. $G$ is a group and $G\triangleright A,B$ are normal subgroups of $G$. Then $G/A\cong G/B \Leftrightarrow A\cong B $.
> 3. $G,H$ are non abelian groups with order of 24 $\Rightarrow G\cong H$.

Answer (score 1):

The groups $\mathbb Z_6$ and $S_3$ are both [extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension) of $\mathbb Z_3$ by $\mathbb Z_2$. $\mathbb Z_6$ is an extension of $\mathbb Z_2$ by $\mathbb Z_3$ but $S_3$ is not. In fact $S_3$ has no normal subgroup of order $2$. This could contradict 1.